# OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

When i type this url direct into browser i get the post sent to user feed wall

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xx facebook uid xx/feed?access_token=xx app access token xx&message=Welcome%20to%20App!&method=post
```

But it gives me this error `OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature.` when i automate the post with this code

```
<?PHP

    include_once "inc/facebook.php";
    require_once 'inc/config.php';

// Create our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => $app_id,
    'secret'    => $app_secret,
    ));

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host.';charset=utf8', $db_username, $db_password );

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT fb_id FROM offline_access_users');

$stmt->execute();

$body = array(
            'message' => 'Test Multiple Messages', 
            'link'    => '',
            'picture' => '',
            'name'    => '',
            'description'=> ''
            );
    $batchPost=array();
    $i=1;       
    foreach ($stmt as $value) {
    $id = $value['fb_id'];

        $batchPost[] = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'relative_url' => "/" . $id . "/feed?access_token=" . $access_token,
            'body' => http_build_query($body) );    
        if($i++ == 50) {
            try {
                $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch=' . urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
                echo "Success";
            } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                echo($e);
            }
            unset($batchPost);
            $i=1;
        }
    }

    if(isset($batchPost) && count($batchPost) > 0 ) {
        try{
            $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch=' . urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
            echo "Success";
        } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            echo($e);
        }
    }


$db = null;


?>
```

I really don't know how to come over this issue. Please help me

Comment: echo the actual url that you're calling within the code and see if it matches with what you expect. There might be a space, etc, that's causing the exception.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks you for your reply, but i have already done what you suggested but unfortunately i found url is same as i am typing directly into the browser. I think there is something wrong with the loop or passing the values to the php post function.